# Dagger2 generating multiple instances of retrofit interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger

Dagger 2 is generating multiple instances of retrofit interceptor despite marking it as singleton in dagger module. Now the problem is that AuthorizationInterceptor constructor gets called twice which I don't understand why and because of that the headers that I set after getting result from login API get sets to a different instance of Interceptor and while making call to some other API which requires authorizationToken the token is unset.

Here is my ApiModule

```
@Module
open class ApiModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    return loggingInterceptor
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHeaderInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    return AuthorizationInterceptor()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor, headerInterceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi.Builder()
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient, moshi: Moshi, apiConfig: ApiConfig): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(apiConfig.baseUrl)
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideFrappApi(retrofit: Retrofit): FrappApi {
    return retrofit.create(FrappApi::class.java)
}
```

Here is my AuthorizationInterceptor class

```
@Singleton
class AuthorizationInterceptor @Inject constructor() : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {
    val request = chain?.request()
    val requestBuilder = request?.newBuilder()
    if (request?.header("No-Authorization") == null && authorization.isNotEmpty()) {
        requestBuilder?.addHeader("Authorization", authorization)
    }
    return chain?.proceed(requestBuilder!!.build())!!
}

private var authorization: String = ""
fun setSessionToken(sessionToken: String) {
    this.authorization = sessionToken
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to make a provide method if you do a constructor injection.

Remove the `provideHeaderInterceptor` method, then update the `provideHttpClient` method like below,

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
        headerInterceptor: AuthorizationInterceptor): OkHttpClient {

    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        .build()
}
```

Or if you dont like the solution above, you can remove the `@Singleton` and `@Inject` in your `AuthorizationInterceptor` class.

Comment: Thanks man it worked I've been banging my head on this from yesterday

Comment: NP, dagger takes time to digest. Best Regards,